# Java regex: match multiple word boundaries

Tags: java, regex

I would like to match couple of words in a text. Have following:

```
if ( Pattern.matches(".*\\b" + placeSub.toLowerCase() + "\\b" + placeSup.toLowerCase() + "\\b.*", sourceText.toLowerCase()) ) {
    System.out.println( String.format("Matched %s on %s", placeSub, placeSup) );        
}
```

The variables `placeSub`, `placeSup` & `sourceText` are dynamic (runtime).

The code above doesn't work (no match). However, the following matches:

```
if ( Pattern.matches(".*\\b" + placeSub.toLowerCase() + "\\s" + placeSup.toLowerCase() + "\\b.*", sourceText.toLowerCase()) ) {
   System.out.println( String.format("Matched %s on %s", placeSub, placeSup) ); 
}
```

Why is the text able to match `\\s` and not `\\b`?

Example input:

1. placeSub : `South`
2. placeSup : `Sudan`
3. sourceText : `tens of thousands of people have fled fierce fighting in south sudan's northern unity state`

Comment: With `placeSub` = `South` and `placeSup` = `Sudan` there can't be just a `\b` between the two. In the example there is, however, a space, which is why `\s` matches.

Comment: Why do you need `.*` there?

Comment: How I am supposed to match 2 words separated by  by unknown characters? The case of `South Sudan` is just an example. It would be `South-Sudan` or something else.

Comment: @MugomaJ.Okomba If they *have to* be separate words: `/word\b.*\bword/`

Comment: `.*` matches anything before and anything after. I could have used `^` & `$` but preferred to leave the expression open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should actually use:

```
Pattern.matches(
   ".*?\\b" + placeSub.toLowerCase() + "\\b\\W+\\b" + placeSup.toLowerCase() + "\\b.*",
   sourceText.toLowerCase())
```

Which will translate into:

```
/.*?\bsouth\b\W+\bsudan\b.*/i
```

[See regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/qK3jY3/1)